# memset() not setting vales to one

Tags: c, arrays, memset

I need to set all values of an array equal to one. I have been trying to do this using the following code:

```
int bulbSwitch(int n) {
    int bulbs[n];
    memset(bulbs, 1, n * sizeof(int));
    ...
```

However, the debugger shows that all values within the array are actually being set to 16843009. Without `memset`, the array values are seemingly random, positive integers. Why is this, and how would I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`memset` sets each **byte** of memory to the value you have specified. An `int` on your platform is clearly 4 bytes. So you are setting each byte of the `int` to be 1.

That is, for each `int`, the code effectively does:

```
bulbs[i] = 0x01010101;
```

That value in decimal is exactly `16843009`.

It means you should not use `memset` but a simple loop instead to set each element of the array.